# tutorial error: setting op the action bar, no resource identifier found for showAsAction

Tags: android-sdk-2.3

Following the Android developpers training step by step the chapter Setting-up-the-action-bar does not work:
The URL for the page is:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Developer%20Documentation

The showAsAction attribute keeps giving an error.
The documentation suggests to add:

```
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
yourapp:showAsAction="..."
```

to 'res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml'

Error message: no resource identifier found for showAsAction.
App will not run at this stage, further progress in training is blocked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. (It's one in a series of complaints about the Android developer's tutorials by the same poster, with no questions being asked in any of them.)

Comment: Once again, this is a question/answer site, and you have not asked a question. This is not a chat room or complaint/rant site. Please review the [about] and [help] pages, and then [edit] your posts to actually ask a question that can be answered by us. We can't do anything about the tutorial content here.